# Laravel: How to execute code before Auth::login()

Tags: php, laravel, logging, laravel-4

I want to log all login events to my log database.

I would like to know if it's possible to use a hook as a preExecute for the default Laravel Auth::login() method?

If so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your auth controller, in the constructor:

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
     // Log $user
});
```